# Sales for each completed month in current year and previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server

For each of the 12 months, I'm looking to create a field that sums the sales dollars at the account level for the most recent month and the 2nd most recent month based on the current date.

For example, given that today's date is 2022-10-28, 'MostRecentNovember' would sum up sales from November 2021. '2ndMostRecentNovember' would sum up sales from November 2020. Once the current date moves into November 2022, this query would adjust to pull MostRecentNovember sales from 2022 and 2ndMostRecentNovember sales from 2021.

Conversely, given that today's date is 2022-10-28 'MostRecentJune' would sum up sales from June 2022 and '2ndMostRecentJune' would sum up sales from June 2021.

In the end state, each account would have 24 fields: January - December for Most Recent and January - December for 2nd most recent

**Below is my attempt at this code, this gets partially there, but it's not getting what I need. I've also tried with a CTE, but that didn't seem to do it either**

```
SELECT NovemberMostRecent_Value = 
       sum(case when datepart(year,tran_date) = datepart(year, getdate())
AND DATEPART(month, tran_date) = 11 then value else 0 end)
       NovemberSecondMostRecent_Value = 
       sum(case when datepart(year,tran_date) = datepart(year, getdate())-1
AND DATEPART(month, tran_date) = 11 then value else 0 end)
```

**Here's a snippet of the source data table**

| account_no | tran_date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-11-22 | 500 |
| 123 | 2021-11-01 | 500 |
| 123 | 2020-11-20 | 1500 |
| 123 | 2022-06-03 | 5000 |
| 123 | 2021-06-04 | 2000 |
| 456 | 2020-11-03 | 525 |
| 456 | 2021-11-04 | 125 |

**A table of desired Results**

| account_no | NovemberMostRecent | November2ndMostRecent | June MostRecent | June2ndMostRecent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1000 | 1500 | 5000 | 2000 |
| 456 | 125 | 525 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Can you present your date values as proper dates ideally yyyymmdd to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @Stu sure thing. Just updated.

Comment: @Stu it's not what I want. Updated language to make that clear. I wouldn't be here asking for help if my example query got me what I need.

Answer (score 0):

We use `dense_rank()` by year desc (partitioned by month) and pivot.

```
select *
from
(
select account_no
      ,value
      ,concat(datename(month, tran_date), '_', dense_rank() over(partition by month(tran_date) order by year(tran_date) desc))  as month_rnk
from   t
) t
pivot (sum(value) for month_rnk in(June_1, June_2, November_1, November_2)) p
```

| account_no | June_1 | June_2 | November_1 | November_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 5000 | 2000 | 1000 | 1500 |
| 456 | null | null | 125 | 525 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dMlutynw)